# Swift 2 self.presentViewController vs segue for simple navigation

Tags: ios, swift2, uikit

I am new to iOS Development and I am using swift2 to develop a simple web application whereby I am unsure of the behaviour of self.presentViewController.

In my MainViewcontroller I have the following codes to redirect user to login viewController

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let signinViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SigninViewController") as! SigninViewController;

self.presentViewController(signinViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

This set of codes work the way I want it to, which will redirect the user to signin page upon starting the application.

However in android development, I have to do a "finish();" to destroy my current stack, and I am unsure whether if I have to follow similar procedure in iOS Development.

---

Next, I have done some research on self.presentViewController versus segue as followed in the given article

[UIStoryboardSegue versus presentviewcontroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604079/uistoryboardsegue-versus-presentviewcontroller)

So am I save to say that my approach in redirecting users from (Main_VC to SignIn_VC) is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You should not destroy presenting view controller in any way, it needs to be there when you get back from presented view controller.

If you do not plan to ever return the previous controller, you can simply replace it with new view controller as your window's (or navigation controller's) root. Since you are presenting sign in controller, this is probably not what you might want to do, just mentioning in for sake of completeness

Comment: Uhm, I'm actually facing a difficulty now, the title I have set on my sign in view controller just doesn't show up, is there any codes that I am missing out? :o

Comment: title shows only if the view controller is embedded inside navigation view controller.

Comment: i did embed it into a navigation controller however it appears as a blank screen without any navigation bar

Comment: Did you embed it in the storyboards? you are creating view controller with Id "SigninViewController" which I think is the SigninViewController itself. What you need to do, is set storyboards Id on the navigation controller that embeds your Signin VC and instantiate navigation VC instead of "SigninViewController"

Comment: "you can simply replace it with new view controller as your window's (or navigation controller's) root". How to do this?